# Samsung Magician - On or Off

Tags: boot

I enabled the Rapid Mode on Samsung Magician. I've read a lot about this topic, but I still want to make sure I'm going for the right choise. Do I need Samsung Magician running on startup or not? Because I've read, for example that, if you run R.A.I.D. you need it on startup. If not, you don't. What I think is that if you've enabled Rapid Mode you don't need it on startup at all. I think that Rapid Mode is separated from Magician and "it's running as if it is another program". I'm not sure tho. So, Samsung Magician -> on or off on Startup?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two machines here with Samsung SSD drives - Laptop with one Drive; Desktop with two independent Drives.

I have Samsung Magician on both machines and updated on both machines (Version 6.21).

It monitors the health of all the drives, does not consume any CPU results and just sits there silently.

No harm at all to run (that is, have it turned ON) and let it sit in the system tray. I am happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung RAPID mode is provided by using 2 filter drivers and a service:

- SamsungRapidDiskFltr.sys
- SamsungRapidFSFltr.sys
- SamsungRapidSvc.exe

They will process all storage reads/writes to **just one** Samsung SSD and cache them in RAM. This functionality is independent from SamsungMagician.exe program. Thus there is no need to run the Samsung Magician at system startup for RAPID mode.